# Older asynchronous messages overwriting newer ones

Tags: asp.net, signalr, keyboard-events

We are developing a document collaboration tool in SignalR where multiple users can update one single WYSIWYG form.

We are struggling getting the app to work using the KeyUp method to send the changes back to the server. This causes the system to overwrite what the user wrote after his first key stroke when it sends the message back.

Is there anyway to work around this problem?

**For the moment I tried to set up a 2 seconds timeout but this delays all updates not only the "writer" page.**

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public ChatHub()
    {

    }

    public void Send(int id,string message)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.     
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(id,message); //id is for the document id where to update the content
    }

}
```

and the client:

```
$(function () {

        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        //console.log("Declare a proxy to reference the hub."); 

        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (id, message) {

            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(id).html();


            // Add the message to the page.  

            if (encodedValue == $('#hdnDocId').val()) {

                $('#DiaplayMsg').text(message);
                tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("");
                tinyMCE.get('txtContent').execCommand('insertHTML', false, message); //!!!


            }
        };

        // Start the connection.

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function (e) {
            //console.log("Start the connection.");

            if ($('#hdnDocId').val() != '') {

                tinyMCE.activeEditor.onKeyUp.add(function (ed, e) {
                    var elelist = $(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody()).text();


                    var content = tinyMCE.get('txtContent').getContent();


                    function Chat() {

                        var content = tinyMCE.get('txtContent').getContent();

        chat.server.send($('#hdnDocId').val(), content); //send a push to server

                    }

                    typewatch(Chat, 2000);
                });
            }
        });

    });
    var typewatch = function () {
        var timer = 0;
        return function (Chat, ms) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(Chat, ms);
        }
    } ();
</script>
```

Hello, here is an update of the client KeyUp code. It seems to be working but I would like your opinion. I've used a global variable to store the timeout, see below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        //console.log("Declare a proxy to reference the hub.");          
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (id, message) {

            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(id).html();

            var currenttime = new Date().getTime() / 1000 - 2
            if (typeof window.istyping == 'undefined') {
                window.istyping = 0;
            }

            if (encodedValue == $('#hdnDocId').val() && window.istyping == 0 && window.istyping < currenttime) {

                function Update() {
                    $('#DiaplayMsg').text(message);
                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("");
                    tinyMCE.get('txtContent').execCommand('insertHTML', false, message); //!!!
                    //                                        tinyMCE.get('txtContent').setContent(message);
                    window.istyping = 0
                }
                Update();
            }
        };

        // Start the connection.

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function (e) {
            //console.log("Start the connection.");

            if ($('#hdnDocId').val() != '') {

                tinyMCE.activeEditor.onKeyUp.add(function (ed, e) {
                    var elelist = $(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody()).text();

                    var content = tinyMCE.get('txtContent').getContent();

                    function Chat() {
                        //alert("Call");
                        var content = tinyMCE.get('txtContent').getContent();
                        chat.server.send($('#hdnDocId').val(), content);
                        window.istyping = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
                    }
                    Chat();

                });
            }
        });

    });
    var typewatch = function () {
        var timer = 0;
        return function (Chat, ms) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(Chat, ms);
        }
    } ();
```

Thanks,
Roberto.

Comment: this isnt something we could possibly answer without seeing your code for, at the very least, how you respond to message coming from the server

Comment: hi Robert, I've added code excerpts to my question. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway to work around this problem?

Yes, by not sending the entire document to the server, but document elements like paragraphs, table cells, and so on. You can synchronize these *after* the user has stopped typing for a period, or when focus is lost for example.

Otherwise add some incrementing counter to the messages, so older return values don't overwrite newer ones arriving earlier.

But you're basically asking us to solve a non-trivial problem regarding collaborated document editing. What have *you* tried?

Comment: So far I've been focusing more on trying to disable the updates for those users that are typing for as long as they type (i.e.: setting a timeout). As the timeout expires their form is updated too and everyone is happy, wouldn't that work?

Comment: Hi, I've used a global JS variable to store a timeout for the writer. Could you advise if you think this is a good way to approach the problem? (as far as I can see it works). I can't add the code here so, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: A timer still can cause the response to message 2 (R2) to arrive earlier than the response to message 1 (R1), causing R1 to overwrite R2.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to narrow down the section of updates. But FYI the solution above does solve the problem. I'll keep you posted. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck. That it works now on your machine doesn't promise it'll work on a slower machine and/or one with a mobile or laggy connection or proxy/loadbalancer/and so on. :-) You'll _have_ to label your update messages in some way, so older messages can never overwrite newer ones.

Comment: no worries, I did take your advice to split the update area in smaller pieces. This is only a prototype to show the stake holder what the final product will look like. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"This causes the system to overwrite what the user wrote"

that's because this code isn't making any effort to merge changes.  it is just blindly overwriting whatever is there.

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("");
tinyMCE.get('txtContent').execCommand('insertHTML', false, message);
```

as @CodeCaster hinted, you need to be more precise in the messages you send - pass specific changes back and forth rather re-sending the entire document - so that changes can be carefully merged on the receiving side